# Is there anyway to use the AddSecretClient DI extension in an azure function?

Tags: c#, azure, dependency-injection, azure-functions, nuget-package

I'm trying to configure some depedancies for my azure function. I need to be able to access (among other things) an azure keyvault. Currently I'm accessing this manually and having to do all my own dependancy injection. This didn't feel right and I went looking for a better way to hook this up. I found [this blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sdk/best-practices-for-using-azure-sdk-with-asp-net-core/) that seems ideal.

> ```
> public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
> {
>   services.AddAzureClients(builder =>
>   {
>     // Add a KeyVault client
>     builder.AddSecretClient(keyVaultUrl);
>
>     // Add a storage account client
>     builder.AddBlobServiceClient(storageUrl);
>
>     // Use the environment credential by default
>     builder.UseCredential(new EnvironmentCredential());
>   });
>
>   services.AddControllers();
> }
> ```

Great I want to do that. Problem is these extensions don't seem to support the particular DI implemented in Azure functions. Specifically there is an incompatibility between the type expected for the `AddSecretClient` and the builder injected into the `Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)`:

```cs
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace Snapshot.Take
{
    [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        

        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            RegisterHttpClients(builder);

            builder.Services.AddLogging();

            //error

            builder.AddSecretClient(new Uri(""));
       }
   }
}
```

> The type
> 'Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IFunctionsHostBuilder'
> cannot be used as type parameter 'TBuilder' in the generic type or
> method
> 'SecretClientBuilderExtensions.AddSecretClient(TBuilder,
> Uri)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from
> 'Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IFunctionsHostBuilder'
> to 'Azure.Core.Extensions.IAzureClientFactoryBuilderWithCredential'.

So is there an Azure function version of these extensions or do I have to roll my own?

Comment: Did you try `builder.Services.AddAzureClients(clientBuilder => )`?

Comment: Yes that's what I was missing @juunas . Do you want to add an answer? I'm open to being proved wrong but I couldn't find this documented anywhere...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `AddAzureClients` is an extension method on `IServiceCollection`,
you'll probably need to do something like:

```cs
  builder.Services.AddAzureClients(clientBuilder =>
  {
    // Add a KeyVault client
    clientBuilder.AddSecretClient(keyVaultUrl);

    // Add a storage account client
    clientBuilder.AddBlobServiceClient(storageUrl);

    // Use the environment credential by default
    clientBuilder.UseCredential(new EnvironmentCredential());
  });
```

Comment: For anyone coming along later, `AddAzureClients()` can be found in package `Microsoft.Extensions.Azure`